# List value reduction algorithm

Tags: algorithm, list, mutation

Forgive me, but I am very confused and I cannot find any sources that are pointing my in the right direction.

Given list of n elements:

```
[3, 6, 5, 1]
```

Reduce the values to be no larger than the size of the list while keeping prioritization values relative to one another (In their original order).

Constraints:

- Order must be maintained
- Elements are >= 0
- Distinct values

I am trying to stay away from sorting and creating a new list, but modifying the list in-place.

What my expected outcome should be:

```
[1, 3, 2, 0]
```

Is there an algorithm that exists for this problem?

Comment: Update: I have found a solution for this problem specifically, but it does not work for all problems especially lists with a large range. http://pastebin.com/jBJXcZtm

Comment: I don't think that's really a solution. I just happens to work for this particular set of values.

Comment: Here is a solution I have been working on improving: http://pastebin.com/21vb9RH5 thanks to @Geobits 's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in O(n^2).

Just go through the list `n` times, setting the minimum element(while `>= i`) to `i` each time, where `i` starts at 0 and increments to `n-1`

I suspect you're looking for something better than that, but I'm not sure how much better you can do in-place.

Example:

```
Input: 3  6  5  1

3  6  5  0*
1* 6  5  0
1  6  2* 0
1  3* 2  0
```

Note: this assumes elements are `>= 0` and distinct

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, your assumptions: "elements are >= 0 and distinct" are correct. I will update my question.

Comment: Good, this will work then. The solution you added in comments doesn't work in most situations, because you're looking for the max value while lowering each max value. It will run into the same element at some point. This way you are only ever moving them downward while looking for the minimum, so they don't interfere.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. I was hoping for a O(2n) solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

There may be one, but you don't need it if you think about the steps needed to take to solve this problem.

First, you know that each value in the array cannot be greater than 4, since that is the size in this particular example.

You need to go through each number in the array and with a if condition check to see if the number is greater; if it is then you'll need to decrement it until it is meets the correct condition (in this case, that it is less than 4).

Perform these steps for each index of the array. As far as order, don't swap any indices, since you must retain the original order. Hope that helps!

Comment: So, in the original input given in the question, how exactly are you decrementing the second and third number (which are originally 6 and 5), while maintaining order? Swapping indices (or the lack thereof) doesn't address this issue at all.

Comment: Hypothetically you could use have a variable that holds the size of the array and check to see the value of the int at a particular index. If it's greater than the size, decrement it until it reaches the desired value. I didn't recommend swapping indices at all; he needs to retain the original order if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The problem is that if I follow your original statement to the letter; 6 and 5 would both be decremented to 3. You'd need something else there to determine how to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Good point, I didn't catch that. Perhaps he could simultaneously compare it to the previous index. That way he would keep the original relation. Thanks for pointing that out though, didn't see that.

Comment: Better, but remember that once you decrement, you lose information about what it was before the decrement. In other words, once you're decrementing 5, if you've already decremented that 6 to a 3, you have no way of confirming that the 3 used to be a 6 without some other data structure.

Comment: I may need to initially scan through the list to retrieve the bounds (`min<->max`)

Comment: Can you use another array to store the original data in for comparison purposes, like Dennis suggested?

Comment: @eulloa I think he said that he'd rather not have to create a second array if he can avoid it.

Comment: I found a pseudo-answer. It only works for this case though. One the range from min to max gets very large, this solution does not work: http://pastebin.com/jBJXcZtm