# Sort-related algorithm (replace each item by its index in the sorted colletion)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

I need to do the following:

Given an `std::vector` of `int` I need to replace each `int` by the index that it would be in if the vector were sorted.

I will try to explain it better with an example.

Input: `{22, 149,31}`

Output: `{2, 0, 1}`

(Note that in the sorted vector {149, 31, 22} the **22** is in the **index 2** of the sorted vector, the **149** is in **index 0**, and the **31** is in **index 1**)

I hope I make the algorithm clear.

Is this implemented somehow in the STL C++11 library? Has this algorithm a name? Can you offer any ideas to implement it elegantly?

Comment: I don't know that it has a name, but it's very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19260078/752320). It looks like you're sorting descending, but other than that it's basically the same problem.

Comment: It's called "sorting with a compare function". You sort the indexes, using the indexed values in the comparison function.

Comment: If your input was `{22, 149, 31, 149}` what would you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think it has a name, but it's pretty easy to accomplish.

First, you create a target vector and fill it with the indices 0...n.

```
vector<int> indices(input.size());
std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);
```

Second, you sort that vector, but instead of comparing the numbers in the vector, you compare the numbers at the relevant index in the input vector.

```
std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
          [&input](int l, int r) { return input[l] < input[r]; });
```

**Edit** Note that I'm sorting in ascending order, whereas you're looking for descending order. Just flip the comparison in the lambda.

Comment: +1 but one minor nitpick: `vector<int> indices; indices.reserve(input.size()); iota_n(std::back_inserter(indices), input.size(), 0);` would be slightly more efficient in generating the indices. For `iota_n` see e.g. [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11767512/819272)